# Angular - Pass info how an opend window was closed to the component from which the window was invoked

Tags: javascript, angular

I am opening a new window (let's call it New Calculation) from a component that is not related to it (Calculation List).

```
const windowHandler: Window = window.open(appUrl);
    const calculateSnackbarInterval = setInterval((): void => {
      this.calculateOpened = true;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      if (windowHandler.closed) {
        this.snackBarService.openSnackBar({
          type: 'info',
          message: this.translate.instant(this.getTranslateKeyForSnackBar()),
          actions: [
            {
              label: this.translate.instant(`snackbar.actions.abort`),
              action: SnackbarAction.ABORT,
            },
          ],
        });
        this.calculateOpened = false;
        this.ref.detectChanges();
        this.pullingIntervalDelete?.unsubscribe();
        clearInterval(this.maximumPullingInterval);
        this.startPullingInterval();
        clearInterval(calculateSnackbarInterval);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

The invoked New Calculation window can be closed by "Cancel" button, using the browser, or pressing the "Calculate" button.

Currently a snackbar appears in Calculation List when closing the New Calculation, it doesn't matter which way was chosen. I would like to invoke this snackbar, only when the New Calculation window is closed using the "Calculate" button.

I have thought about 2 possible solutions:

1. Using local storage to save the information which button was used to close the window, and read it from the `windowHandler`.
   Cons: Not sure about the security aspect, I would like to avoid the user tampering with it, and the user can edit local storage.
2. Build a dedicated service that reacts to an event assigned to "Calculate" button.
   Cons: This one seems like an overkill for me with all of the listeners and dependencies.

Is there a preferred method to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is soliciting opinions and is not appropriate for stack overflow.

Comment: thinking about the two solutions, I'll go with the second one. Unless there is some way you set some information to windows object, that you can check before it closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came up with a simple solution. It's not the prettiest practice, however
it doesn't seem to be an overkill and user won't be able to tamper with it easily.

On the button triggering a new calculation I've added:

```
(this.window as any).calculationStarted = true;
```

and simply changed the receiver to

```
if (windowHandler.closed && (windowHandler as any).calculationStarted) {
```